# How to add a catch all to an htaccess redirect regular expression?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following line in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/r/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?slug_1=$1&slug_2=$2&ref=$3 [L]
```

So, blah.com/a/b/r/c/ goes to blah.com?slug_1=a&slug_2=b&ref=c

I would also like to catch and append all extra query params

So if I go to blah.com/a/b/r/c?d=e&f=g then it redirects to blah.com?slug_1=a&slug_2=b&ref=c&d=e&f=g

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule is correct but you need `QSA` flag:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)/([^/.]+)/r/([^/.]+)/?$ /index.php?slug_1=$1&slug_2=$2&ref=$3 [L,QSA]
```

`QSA` is called `Q`uery `S`tring `A`ppend that preserves original query string while adding new one.